# working out a percentage from my email open rates

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, divisibility

i have the following numbers:

recipients: $95$

opens: $39$

bounces: $2$

how would i get the percentage value per open?

accoridng to this post: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2395/all-about-email-open-rates

i would do the following:

open rate = opens / emails sent - bounces

Comment: Did you mean to have parentheses around (emails sent - bounces)?  It would seem so, as if you had 2 opens and 39 bounces out of 95 the rate would be negative.  Parentheses are important.  The site you link to gets it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should think open rate = opens / (emails sent - bounces) * 100% would be more to the point. Order of operations is important!

If you want the percentage for one open in your whole set of emails, then you would just do (open rate for one open) = 1 / (emails sent - bounces) * 100%.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I want the $\LaTeX$ version here, Danny. Thanks, though. The parentheses emphasize the difference in order of operations from what the OP wrote. From a pedagogical point of view, the $\LaTeX$ version with the nice fraction would hide the difference I'm trying to point out.